# How to remove a stack from backStack?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I have an activity which manages 4 fragments. I would like that, when I add a fragment to backStack, it removes the same fragments from backStack (if there is one) in order to have only one fragment in backstack at the time. If user goes from A to B to C, and goes back to B, The back stack looks like: C,A instead of C,B,A.

I've looked for a solution to my problem and I've found that a lot of people had the same problem. The most suggested solution was to use `popBackStackImmediate(String, int)` but the enormous problem is that this function removes the stacks on top of the stack that has been popped. This behaviour seems to be unchangeable. So I imagined a solution which consist to run through BackStack with a for loop, and when I have a match between my fragment's tag and a fragment's in the BackStack, I delete the stack. I think this stack is a `fragmentTransaction` so I wondered if it was possible to delete a whole Fragment Transaction and how to do that?

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        String tagFromFragAddedToBackStack = getCurrentFragment().getTag();
        String fragmentTag = fragment.getClass().getName();
        String fragFromBackStackTag;
        FragmentTransaction fragTransFromBackStack;
        int i;

        for ( i = 0; i < manager.getBackStackEntryCount() ; i++){

                fragFromBackStackTag = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName();
                fragTransFromBackStack = (FragmentTransaction) manager.getBackStackEntryAt(i);
                fragFromBackStack = manager.findFragmentByTag(fragFromBackStackTag);

                if (fragFromBackStackTag == fragmentTag){

              // Here, I would like to delete the stack which matches 

                }
            }
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment, fragmentTag);
            ft.addToBackStack(tagFromFragAddedToBackStack); 
            ft.commit();
    }

  private Fragment getCurrentFragment(){
        if (homeFragment.isVisible()){
            return homeFragment;
        }
        else if (autonomyFragment.isVisible()) {
            return autonomyFragment;
        }
        else if (shopFragment.isVisible()) {
            return shopFragment;
        }
        else if (accountFragment.isVisible()) {
            return accountFragment;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: @TaseerAhmad cause the interpretation of the title could be very different

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)